# Sonarqube Plugin development

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am trying to develop a plugin for Sonar which can get input from some third party API and get some results, Third party API will give me details such as Line number and file name, I want to put a link to that file and line on sonar widget, Can anyone help me, how can I create a link to particular file and line on Sonar widget

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to learn a bit about developing plugins for SonarQube because the question you asked is very generic and so extense to answer.
Here are some links to get some information about the development:

[http://docs.sonarqube.org](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Developing+Plugins)

[https://deors.wordpress.com (sweet intro tutorial)](https://deors.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/sonarqube-plugins-1/)

The plugin you want to seems pretty simple so easy to implement. The main class that you should have to work on is the **Sensor**, where you would like to create issues referring the code-files and the lines on it.